# Get a Named Range as a Collection in Blueprism

Tags: excel, named-ranges, blueprism

The BluePrism Excel VBO has `Get Worsheet As Collection` and `Get Worksheet Range as Collection` actions, but as an experienced VBA developer, I know it is better to refer to to named ranges. *(It makes you less vulnarable to rearangements of the Excel)*

I do not find an **action to get the content of a Named Range as a Collection**, though. If it exists, how is it called, and if it does not, can one achieve the same in a simple way?

*(Or better, can I create it in C# and and share it with my colleagues?)*

Comment: To use C# you'll have to rewrite at least "Global code" part of VBO in C#. Some internal stuff won't work otherwise.

Comment: Does this comment apply to the answer of Andrzey Kaczor?

Comment: It applies to any VBO - you can't have code stages in different languages within same VBO. GetWorksheet is internal VBO function, so you'll have to rewrite that (and others). Andrzej is talking about extending original VBO in VB.net.

Answer (score 3):

When I am working with named ranges, then i use two actions:

1. Get named range address
2. Get Worksheet Range as a collection

The second one is a standard blueprism utility, so thats something that you have ready at your disposal. The code for the "Get named range address" is not really complicated, as it is only one line of code:

```
Address = GetWorksheet(handle,sWB,sWS).Range(sRange).Address
```

The result is a string that represent a range in a format $A$1:$B$2. The "Get Worksheet range as collection" required one input for "Start cell", and one for "end cell", so to combine these functions then you'll need to split it and send one part of address as "start cell", and the other as "end cell".

As a matter of fact, you can also improve the standard "get worksheet as collection" to accept a range in that format, as it's pretty simple thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can treat the excel as database, and you can query on Excel sheet using OLEDB. 
Connection string to excel would be :

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=[FilePath];Extended Properties="Excel 12.0;HDR=YES";
```

While querying on excel sheet just give the column name in which format or order and you will get it.

```
select [column1],[column2],... from [SheetName$]
```

or

```
select [column2], [column1], .... from [SheetName$]
```

This will return a collection with headers names as named in excel headers.